# Twilio send dtmf to inbound call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, dtmf

Is it possible to have Twilio to send "out of tune"-dtmf to an inbound call?

I'm building a custom VoiP phone and using Twilio to manage all the logic in the cloud, but the phone should take certain actions when Twilio tells it so.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can play DTMF tones to any call using the [`<Play>` TwiML with the `digits` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play#attributes-digits).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you @philnash, would the <play> dtmf be out of tune?

Comment: Oh, out of tune? No, it would be in tune and play the right tones. I guess you could record the out of tune tones you want to play to the phone and use  `<Play>` with the URL to the recording.